# R Studio font outputs

Tags: rstudio

I'd like to understand how to change the text that is output in the source pane of R Studio. For instance, when I issue the command data(), to view the built in data sets, the output is displayed in what might be Time New Roman and it is quite small and not nicely formatted. I've been able to successfully change the console text size and type with the Global Options, or Preferences selections. 
In addition, my output code chunks in R Markdown documents are likewise in possibly New Times Roman, not Monaco, or Courier, or whatever font I change to with the Preferences or Options. I'd like to have the code chunk outputs look better formatted, and in the font of my choice. I also have no problem manipulating the R Markdown font - it is output of the code chunks that is in the same font as the output at my source pane. I've included a screen shot. Any suggestions?

[font differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw4v8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Appears that this might have been an R Studio version issue. I just updated to 1.2.5019 and all the fonts are the same now - both in the console window and in R Markdown chunk outputs.